# How do I find out if I am the topmost page and not an iframe, web worker, service worker, popup, etc?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to detect if the current javascript context is running as the parent-most html page and not a nested iframe, web worker, service worker, or pop up window.

What's the most reliable way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

```
if(window.self && window.top && window.self !== window.top){
  console.log('in iframe');
}else{
  console.log('not in iframe');
}
```